# Playback of freehand drawing

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I have a canvas, on which freehand drawing can be done (similar to this http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/drawing-in-wp7-2-drawing-shapes-with-finger). My requirement is, I have to make the drawing play and pause programaticaly. There is button, on click the drawing should be played the way it was drawn. Please guide me what steps should be taken to acheive this, also if there is any sample application or link is available. Thanks.

Comment: I was trying to capture the points, the way I am capturing while drawing, and keeping them in an array. I dint get any idea on how to play it. Is there any way to store the time for all points, so that depending on the time taken from one point to another ,it can be redrawn automatically?

Answer (score 0):

**Update: I finally got around to fixing this so it works in Windows Phone 7, and not just WPF.**

Based on the example you cited.

Define a list of Points:

```
private List<Point> _points;
```

When the LeftMouseButton is Down *AND* Up add a blank point and the starting point:

```
oldPoint = currentPoint;
_points.Add(new Point(-1, -1));
_points.Add(oldPoint);
```

Your Play button event handler will look like this:

```
canvas.Children.Clear();

// Use the BackgroundWorker to draw the lines
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

The worker_DoWork iterates through _points and sends them on to our dispatcher:

```
void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
        for (int ix = 0; ix < _points.Count - 1; ix++)
        {
            Point start = _points[ix];
            Point end = _points[ix + 1];

            if (start.X == -1 || end.X == -1)
                continue;

            Thread.Sleep(10);
            DoEvents(start, end);
        }
}
```

DoEvents uses the `Dispatcher` to send the line coordinates to a delegated method

```
    private delegate void AddLineDelegate(Point p1, Point p2);

    private void DoEvents(Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new AddLineDelegate(AddLine), new object[] { p1, p2 });
    }

    private void AddLine(Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        Line line = new Line() { X1 = p1.X, Y1 = p1.Y, X2 = p2.X, Y2 = p2.Y };
        line.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        line.StrokeThickness = 4;
        this.canvas.Children.Add(line);
    }
```

Comment: I have a doubt on the DispatcherFrame. I added the namespace system.windows.threading, but still its saying namespace coulnot be found. I am new to this technology, so unable to trace out the exact solution. Need your help. Thanks.

Comment: @Shri Nearly a year later I have updated the answer to get the playback working smoothly in Windows Phone 7